# define base URL globally in Axios plugin for Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my Vue.js project, I have created a plugin for Axios using the instructions from [here](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/) so that Axios will be available globally in the project.  The pertinent code in my project looks like this:

**in src/plugins/axios.js -**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  install: function(Vue) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$axios', { value: axios });
  }
}
```

**in src/main.js -**

```
import axios from './plugins/axios';
Vue.use(axios);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    console.log(this.$axios ? 'axios plugin works' : 'axios plugin does not work');
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

The console is outputting `axios plugin works` so all is well to this point.

In a file that uses Axios, there are several hard coded URLs.  Shown below is just one example of a method from the file:
**src/forms/official-scenarios.vue -**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
                errors: [],
                officialScenarios: []                
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getOfficialScenarios() {
            this.$axios
            .get('https://localhost/myapp/api/scenariolog')
            .then(response => {
                this.officialScenarios = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errors.push(error);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getOfficialScenarios(); 
    },
}
```

What I'd like to do is define a base URL globally for `https://localhost/myapp/api` and reference that in each method that uses `this.$axios`.  How that that be defined?  Then what does the usage look like in `official-scenarios.vue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up modifying **src/plugins/axios.js** as follows -

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'myapp/api/'
});

export default {
  install: function(Vue) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$axios', { value: instance });
  }
}
```

Since Axios supports relative paths, `https://localhost/` was stripped out of the baseURL string.

Then usage in `getOfficialScenarios()` method **src/forms/official-scenarios.vue** became this -

```
getOfficialScenarios() {
    this.$axios
    .get('scenariolog')
    .then(response => {
        this.officialScenarios = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.errors.push(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the base URL in the axios object itself. It should look something like:

```
// Set base URL
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.baseURL || process.env.apiUrl || '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a .env files and call it with a globaly var in vue or in the store (vuex), like API_URL: process.env.API_URL and this.$store.state.API_URL (or getter)

Check [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

You can also create a axios instance and use it

Check [this](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is seeing this in Vue 3, I took the above accepted answer and changed it slightly:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'myapp/api/'
});

export default Vue => Vue.provide('$axios', instance)
```

You can also if wanting to configure your URL based on environment (good idea), is to use environment variables to do exactly that. So you could instead of having 'myapp/api/', you could (when using vite), instead use:

```
import.meta.env.VITE_AXIOS_BASE_URL
```

Hope that helps :)